# build gradle causes the App to generate errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 1.4.1. any project when i open it in Android Studio, all the classes of the project are loaded correctly and the projects work fine.
the problem is when i try to opn a specific project named "EcoAssistant_03", i receive the following message:

```
Error:(22, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'EcoAssistant_03' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

I do not know what is wrong whith project, and i do not know how to get it running correctly.

please have a look at the build.gradle files posted below, and let me know how to get it running

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {
}
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.com.ecoassistant_03"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/Jama-1.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/drivingEfficiencyModuleRunnable_00_out.jar')
}
```

**update**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error tells you the exact problem.

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Remove this `android` section from the top level build.gradle. The Android plugin hasn't been applied to that file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {
}
```

---

That'll fix the problem, but here's some notes

These lines aren't necessary. You already are compiling them with the first line of the dependencies section

```
compile files('libs/Jama-1.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/drivingEfficiencyModuleRunnable_00_out.jar')
```

And this line compiles the two that follow it, so those are not necessary either

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

In other words, this is all you need to build the app

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: i updated my question, now, i found that theres a project called "myapplication" is among the the files of the my main project "ecoassistant_03" and there are three gradle files as shown in the image. how to get rid of that extra project "myapplication", i have not created it

Comment: Is it preventing anything from building? Is it included in the `settings.gradle`? If no, then it isn't doing anything and you are welcome to delete it

Comment: setting.gradle contains the follwoing: include ':app', ':myapplication', ':myapplication'

Comment: So, it's including it twice... Why? Are you sure you didn't try to make a new application in that project?

Comment: Try it. The worst thing that happens is you restore from the recycle bin